# Powershell hashtables

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I would like to use in my scripts **hashtable** from external file. I red about *psm1, *psd1 but unfortunately don't know how to use it. 
Let say, I have hashtables as shown on below example:

```
$hash1 = @{ "TEST_A1"   = "A1_XXXX"
            "TEST_A2"   = "A2_YYYY"}
            
$hash2 = @{ "TEST_B1"   = "B1_XXXX"
            "TEST_B2"   = "B2_YYYY"}
```

Please advice how to get the specific hastable values from external file.

Answer (score 0):

Pls create first hastable.psd1 (psd1= PowerShell Data file), then call (with `Import-LocalizedData`) it from another ps1 (Powershell) script file.

If hashtable.psd1 is in another directory, it should be defined after `-BaseDirectory` parameter.

hashtable.psd1:

```
@{
    hash1 = @{
        "TEST_A1" = "A1_XXXX"
        "TEST_A2" = "A2_YYYY"
    }

    hash2 = @{
        "TEST_B1" = "B1_XXXX"
        "TEST_B2" = "B2_YYYY"
    }
}
```

Client (client.ps1) (assumed client ps1 and hashtable.psd1 are in the same directory):

```
$external = Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory . -FileName hashtable.psd1

$valueA1 = $external.hash1["TEST_A1"]
$valueB2 = $external.hash2["TEST_B2"]

Write-Host "ValueA1: $valueA1"
Write-Host "ValueB2: $valueB2"
```

Output:

```
ValueA1: A1_XXXX
ValueB2: B2_YYYY
```